# Crontab not giving results

Tags: linux, bash, cron, sh

I am not in the root,
I entered the following commands in the crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/ajain/testscript.sh
```

The file testscript.sh has the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "The script begins now"
ping -c 2 live.com
echo The script has been run on `date` >> /home/ajain/testscript.log
echo "The script ends now"
exit
```

The crontab is not giving the results, however, the following command is giving the result in the testscript.log file correctly, displaying the ping date.

```
bash testscript.sh
```

Why is the crontab not working?

Comment: chmod 755 /home/ajain/testscript.sh has already been given.

Comment: Did you not get any email from cron?

Comment: you should just get "The script has been run on `date`" in /home/ajain/testscript.log.

Comment: @WanmingZhang , I am getting this result if the script is run manually, but not via the crontab.

Comment: @TobySpeight How to check emails from cron? Will i have to login as root?

Comment: Just checked, email says that testscript.sh is not a directory.

Comment: The right answer was to mention the following command in the crontab: */1 * * * * bash /home/ajain/testscript.sh
The word bash was missing hence the script was not getting executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it in two different ways.

1. To provide full path to the script  /home/ajain/testscript.sh. Here you don't even need to add `bash` because you have clearly mentioned in which `shell` your script should run i.e. first line of your script `#!/bin/bash`
2. Add this line before executing the script

   ```
    set path=$path:/home/ajain/

    testscript.sh # no need to use bash in front of it
   ```

Also providing execution permission to a script is not just enough. You need to check whether the user who is going to execute the script has permission to the location of the script or not. That means whether user can do a `cd /home/ajain/` or not.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Your answer does not convey why the crontab is not working. Both the solutions given by you works for manually executing the script but the crontab is not yet working. Kindly advise.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned is your cron-tab user has permission to location `/home/ajain/` ? File permission is not enough. Your cron tab account must be added to the group owner of file system `/home/ajain/`. Just execute `touch /home/ajain/testfile.txt` and see whether file has been created or not. Also execute `ls -ltr ` inside `home/ajain/` and check the group and owner of the file system and add your crontab user to that group.

Comment: I am able to access /home/ajain and execute touch /home/ajain/testfile.txt as well.

Comment: Just execute below command from your crontab and check whether working or not. `echo "Hello World!" > /tmp/helloworld.txt`

Comment: The Terminal is giving an error saying "/temp/crontab.RqQQSt" :2 Bad Minute, upon executing this code.

Comment: The right answer was to mention the following command in the crontab: */1 * * * * bash /home/ajain/testscript.sh
The word bash was missing hence the script was not getting executed

Answer (score 0):

You need do define script output.

Because of cron man page:

> When executing commands, any output is mailed to the owner of the
>   crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in
>   the crontab, if such exists). The children copies of cron running
>   these processes have their name coerced to uppercase, as will be seen
>   in the syslog and ps output.

Fore everything else than `echo The script has been run on 'date' >> /home/ajain/testscript.log` you should check your/root's mail, or the syslog (eg. /var/log/syslog).

I could recommend make something like this:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/ajain/testscript.sh >> /home/ajain/script.log
```

@Edit

My crontab file on my user:

```
$crontab -l
# test
*/1 * * * * /home/3sky/tests/test.sh >> /home/3sky/tests/log.log
```

Script look like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "The script begins now"
ping -c 2 live.com
echo The script has been run on `date`
echo "The script ends now"
exit
```

Permission on files:

```
test.sh - 0755/-rwxr-xr-x
log.log - 0644/-rw-r--r--
```

Output in log file:

```
$tail -20 log.log
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 10999ms

The script has been run on Thu Jun 21 12:18:12 CEST 2018
The script ends now
The script begins now
PING live.com (204.79.197.212) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- live.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 10999ms

The script has been run on Thu Jun 21 12:19:12 CEST 2018
The script ends now
The script begins now
PING live.com (204.79.197.212) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- live.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 10999ms

The script has been run on Thu Jun 21 12:20:12 CEST 2018
The script ends now
```

Comment: */1 * * * * /home/ajain/testscript.sh >> /home/ajain/script.log, This code is not yet giving the result in the log file.

Comment: The edited reply is giving the results manually but not via the crontab

Comment: Also, error email in the root says that testscript.sh is not a directory, bad request.

Comment: I have no idea what is your problem. I past here complete 'workflow' with permission, full content of the script, list from crontab, and `tail` logfile. Everything work from crontab.

Comment: The right answer was to mention the following command in the crontab: */1 * * * * bash /home/ajain/testscript.sh
The word bash was missing hence the script was not getting executed

Comment: If you make the script executable, for example: `chmod +x script` and you have `#!/bin/bash` as the first line in your script, `bash` in not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

remove `>> /home/ajain/script.log`, just add line to the top of file `/home/ajain/testscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec >> /home/ajain/script.log 2>&1

echo "The script begins now"
ping -c 2 live.com
echo "The script has been run on `date`"
echo "The script ends now"
exit
```

remove `>> /home/ajain/script.log` from crontab, just using:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/ajain/testscript.sh
```